# Can I use the same label for different entries with multiple bibliographies?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, bibunits

I work on fairly large documents that put together many seperate `*.tex` files as well as seperate `*.bib` files made by different people. I am using `bibunits` package for bibliographies after each project that I include into my document -- I do not have a global bibliography.

Currently, I am trying to solve the following problem: when I have two different `*.bib` files but they contain the same bibliography-entry with the same abbreviation, my second `\cite` refers to the first bibunit-bibliography instead of the second one.

How do I prevent `bibunits` from referring to another bibunit than the one I am citing in?

To clarify:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[subsectionbib]{bibunits}
\defaultbibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{document}

\begin{bibunit}
\cite{source} %first citation
\putbib[references1]
\end{bibunit}

%I need a barrier here, because..

\begin{bibunit}
\cite{source} %this second citation uses the numbering from the first bibunit
\putbib[references2] %instead of referring to this bibunit
\end{bibunit}

\end{document}
```

Now, I know I could just rename the entry in *references2*. However, it's not possible for me to check every single entry in the approx. 40 `*.bib` files that are used in the document and I am looking for a permanent solution. I would also prefer not to merge the different `*.bib` files into one.
Any ideas?